# Open Featured Image Modal in WordPress Gutenberg onClick of a button

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I am using the metabox.io plugin. I am looking for a way to open the new WordPress Gutenberg editors featured image modal onClick of a button inside my custom metabox.

Is there a function that I can use in order to make the featured image modal popup onClick of a button?

Basically, I want to replicate the functionality of the onClick of “Set featured image”.

[image]

So the Featured Image Modal pops up.

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have this working in the classic editor? If so, does that code not work as is in GB?

Comment: Yes, I had it working in the classic editor by calling: wp.media.featuredImage.frame().open(); That's not working in Gutenberg though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the new block editor uses the same media library API, though it's a little weird that you're duplicating the featured image UI. Even if you manage to open that UI, you'd then need to update the editor to use the new selection for its internal data, and listen out for when the other featured image UI is used and update your own

Comment: In Gutenberg, wp.media.featuredImage.frame().open(); opens the featured image modal the same as it did in the classic editor. It just doesn't set it in the sidebar Featured Image metabox after you add the image. I know the featured image metabox is now a React component. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Also, I already have my image in my metabox updating in both Gutenberg and the Classic editor, that part is worked out.

Comment: Yes, in Gutenberg, the internal state determines the UI, not the other way around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved for me by Brandon Payton on Wordpress.org's Gutenberg support forum:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/open-featured-image-modal-in-wordpress-gutenberg-onclick-of-a-button/

He was even awesome enough to create a gist:

https://gist.github.com/brandonpayton/2c30c6175702adb12a093cf258d754d2

You the man Brandon!!